# How to set Dynamic $baseURL on app->config->app.php using codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4, base-url

I got the error on IDE "Syntax error unexpected variable $_SERVER"
and app
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$http_https' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\laragon\www\laplacegroup\app\Config\App.php on line 30"

I am setting my base url in app.php to:

```
protected $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$http_https = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://";
public $baseURL = $http_https . $host;
```

How can fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I use is to dynamically define a variable in `app/Config/Constants.php` and use it in `app/Config/App.php`.

**App.php :**

```php
public $baseURL = BASE_URL;
```

**Constants.php :**

```php
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$http_https = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://";
$baseURL = $http_https . $host;
define('BASE_URL', $baseURL);
```

It works but seems like a bit hacky in my opinion. I never tried to find out if a better solution exists though.