# Multi Tenancy SAAS Application in Codeigniter4 Dynamically configuring database

Tags: php, multi-tenant, saas, codeigniter-4

I am trying to build a multi tenancy saas Application using Codeigniter4. I want to setup individual database for each tanent's data and one global database for users.
I want application to automatically switch to tanent's database based on the tanent id of the logged in user. for this I have identified the tanents subdomain as follows in
`app/config/constants.php`

```
if(!defined('myHostName')){
    $sd=explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

        //define('myHostName', $host);
    if($sd[0]=='localhost')
        define('dbname', 'defaultdb');
    else
        define('dbname', $sd[0]);
```

These codes identify the subcomain and define the dbname as the name of subdomain if call is from subdomain. Then I have defined two database groups in app/config/database.php as follows.

```
public $default = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' =>  'db_blog',
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];

    public $data = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' =>  myHostName,
        'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => false,
        'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swapPre'  => '',
        'encrypt'  => false,
        'compress' => false,
        'strictOn' => false,
        'failover' => [],
        'port'     => 3306,
    ];
```

This is working fine but Now I want the select database dynamically based on the folder on the domain e.g for
tenant 1 the baseurl will be `https://example.com/tenant1`
tenant 2 the baseurl will be `https://example.com/tenant2`
tenant 3 the baseurl will be `https://example.com/tenant3`

the problem here is that first segment (in this case `tenant1/tenant2/tenant3`) are identified as controller by the codeigniter4, I assume that there must be some method to identify the foldername on sites url
or solution may be similar to `https://www.sandeeprajoria.in/2013/05/multi-tenancy-with-codeigniter.html`

Comment: I have to assume, since your links do not name a controller, that there is only one controller on your service. In which case you can set it as your default controller and then use the URL helper to take the first segment of the url and choose your database. If you do have multiple controllers, I would advise altering your url's to match the pattern CodeIgniter expects. Failing that, you can probably do some magic with routes to get what you want.

Comment: One way you could do this is to group all the routes and use segment substitute and follow this by a middleware which will be responsible for changing the database and throwing the error.

Comment: @Jerry This is to clearify that the application is not using single controller.

Answer (score 0):

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65790279/how-to-set-dynamic-baseurl-on-app-config-app-php-using-codeigniter-4' shown me how to answer to my problem.
$baseURL is the constant that is prefixed to all the urls and if I change it dynamically I can access this variable in Constants.php file. Since I can not create or modify variables in database.php I created a constant in constants.php and dynamically assigned the name of database to be used for a specific tenant to that constant. constants defined in Constants.php are available in database.php so I could dynamically configure the database for specific tenant.
Any better idea to achieve similar solution is most welcome.

Comment: The question was actually related to the dynamic selection of database based on tenant. I could achieve this by modifying the constants.php file. The above post gave me an idea how can I dynamically configure $baseURL so that I can extract the foldername assigned to the tenant and based on folder name assign the name of the database to the tanent.